# Mbeya-Tabora road condition

Tags: driving, tanzania

What is the condition of Mbeya-Tabora road? Google maps shows the distance as 584 km and estimated travel (driving) time of a whole 10 hours!

Comment: What research have you done beyond asking google for the driving time and distance?

Comment: Do you find 10 hours an unexpectedly high or low number? Why?